# how to trigger onclick function in Html Check box when its status changed to checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which lists the Employee. In the left side of the list i have checkboxes to select. So, i have Select all checkbox also in header.When i click on select all check box it will selects all check boxes below. But i have javascript in onclick event for checkboxes in down not for select all checkbox. when i select all the checkboxes using select all, the below checkbox onclik event is not getting called. i verified with onchange, onselect event also.

```
<display:column style="width:2%"
                                    title="<input type='checkbox' id='allCheck' name='allCheck' value='propertyConcernId'
                            onclick='checkAll(this);'/>">
                                    <s:checkbox name="propertyConcernId" fieldValue="%{prtyCrnId}" tabindex="7"
                                        id="check_%{#attr.row.propertyId}"
                                        onclick="verifyCheckAll(this);assignValue('select_%{#attr.row.propertyId}','check_%{#attr.row.propertyId}')" />
                                </display:column>
```

how to get this done?Help on this.

```
verifyCheckAll = function(childCheckBox) {
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var isAllChecked = true; 
      $("input:checkbox[name="+childCheckBox.name+"]").each(function() {           
           if (this.checked == false) {
                isAllChecked = false;
           }       
      });    
      $("input[name=allCheck]").attr('checked', isAllChecked);
    isRecSelected(childCheckBox.name);
    }); 

}
```

This is the script i am using to select the child check boxes

Comment: not sure what s:checkbox is. but on the input[type=checkbox] tag the onclick="checkAll(this);" should fire. is the problem with checkAll method not being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by the following way,

```
callChildClick = function(parentChkBox) {   

    var checked_status = parentChkBox.checked;

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("input:checkbox[name="+parentChkBox.value+"]").each(function() {
            this.click();
        });
    });
    isRecSelected(parentChkBox.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the checkAll() function go to every checkbox you have and call for each what you have in onClick event for propertyConcernId fields.

Comment: thats not possible. arugument get chaged dynamically for each check box.